# gensim tfidf number of unique tokens v.s. number of features

Tags: gensim

I'm wondering why isn't the number of features the same as the number of unique tokens, but rather, in my case, they differ by one (1236 v.s. 1235)

> 2018-06-19 04:54:45,158 : INFO : adding document #0 to Dictionary(0 unique tokens: [])
>
> 2018-06-19 04:54:45,182 : INFO : built Dictionary(1236 unique tokens: ['.', ':', .....]...) from 98 documents (total 10007 corpus positions)
>
> 2018-06-19 04:54:45,214 : INFO : collecting document frequencies
>
> 2018-06-19 04:54:45,215 : INFO : PROGRESS: processing document #0
>
> 2018-06-19 04:54:45,219 : INFO : calculating IDF weights for 98 documents and 1235 features (6993 matrix non-zeros)

Comment: tfidf models typically eliminate stop words as well as tokens that occur too often or too infrequently. Without seeing your code it's hard to say what's happening here though.

Comment: @polm23 thanks for your comment! that must be it, though I'd assume the documentation would be more explicit about it maybe